# When to use "throw" and when to use "toss"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have never been able to spot the difference between ***throw*** and ***toss***.

For instance, both of these sentences make perfect sense to me:

> He is going to **toss** a rock at you.
>
> He is going to **throw** a rock at you.

How should I know when to use one or the other?

Comment: As the others say, "toss" implies launching the projectile at a lower velocity, possibly with an "underhand" motion.  "Throw" implies a more forceful launch of the projectile, probably "overhand".  But the distinction is not etched in stone, and the words are, to a degree, interchangeable.  Eg, one might either "throw" or "toss" a towel to someone who requests one, and neither would be considered "odd".

Comment: @HotLicks I agree.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks, but with the change of *implies* to *suggests* (which is anyway what the rest of that comment says).

Comment: a toss is a soft throw

Comment: Toss is more often used with "to" instead of "at."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Toss*** has a more casual, lighter, connotation than ***throw*** which is a more powerful and deliberate action.

One ***tosses*** a towel to one's club mate in the dressing room, but out on the field of play one ***throws*** the ball hard in from the boundary.

*Toss* to me always suggests an underarm movement, whilst *throw* involves the full overarm  action.

This is only an approximate answer to the question and there are no hard and fast rules. You may well hear usages which do not conform exactly to what I have said.

*Toss* also has some sexual and slang connotations but no point in going into those here.

Comment: "...but no point in going into those here" except that I've never heard someone described as having "thrown their cookies".

Comment: "He climbed to the top of the tower and threw himself off" is a description of suicide in British English. The corresponding phrase with the other verb would  have a *completely* different meaning. Be cautious with the word 'toss' in Britain.

Comment: +1 for 'This is only an approximate answer to the question and there are no hard and fast rules. You may well hear usages which do not conform exactly to what I have said.'! (I'm imagining a casual, lighter toss of a caber. I suppose it's a bit naughty to mention 'tossing a party / wobbly / precipitate.'

Comment: I think the distinction has more to do with the trajectory than the motion.  High arc, low speed = toss, low arc, high speed = throw.

Comment: @LorenPechtel As Edwin has mentioned the event in the Highland Games known as *[Tossing the Caber](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&site=&source=hp&q=tossing+the+caber&oq=tossing+the+caber&gs_l=hp.3..35i39j0l4j0i22i30l5.1351.5160.0.6460.18.18.0.0.0.0.125.1548.13j4.17.0....0...1.1.64.hp..2.16.1502.0.cr0L8UjBt30)* does belie much of what we have been saying!

Comment: Proximity is also "key" here. If I toss the car keys to someone, I am close to them, there's little force involved  but if I have to throw them the keys, perhaps we are much farther apart.

Answer (score 2):

You can **toss someone a rock** (so that person can examine it, for instance), but you **throw a rock at someone** to hurt them.

> [toss](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/toss_1): to throw something, especially something light, with a **quick gentle movement** of your hand

In addition, *toss* often implies an upward motion:

> toss: to throw upward

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=toss))

Comment: But the "at" is also important. Throwing something *to* someone is very different to throwing it *at* someone.

Comment: @ChrisH Of course. And "throw up" is something else entirely.